# Can I include a display name when sending email from the AWS SES Javascript v3 SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I'd like to send an email with a from (source) address that includes a display name, like so:

```
      const command = new Ses.SendEmailCommand({
      Destination: {
        ToAddresses: [ 'some-recipient@test.com' ],
      },
      Source: 'John Doe <jdoe@test.com>',
      Message: {
        Subject: {
          Data: 'some subject',
        },
        Body: {
          Html: {
            Data: 'some html message',
          }
        }
      }
    })
    const response = await this.client.send(command)
```

However, this fails with a "MessageRejected" response. If I replace the source with just "jdoe@test.com", then it works fine. How can I include a display name?

Note that I also tried `"John Doe" <jdoe@test.com>` with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed supported. The mistake was elsewhere in the message attributes. For record, the correct format is `John Doe <jdoe@test.com>`, without the quotes around the display name.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
"John Doe" <johndoe@example.com>
```

Doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/email-format.html

Comment: I should have mentioned I also tried that. Same result unfortunately.